# Validating a non-existent field error in console

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

My problem is I am getting this error when I try to validate my fields with VeeValidate on my system.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: [vee-validate] Validating a non-existent field: "". Use "attach()" first.
    at createError (vee-validate.esm.js?00d1:297)
    at Validator._handleFieldNotFound (vee-validate.esm.js?00d1:2282)
    at Validator.validate (vee-validate.esm.js?00d1:1959)
    at ScopedValidator.validate (vee-validate.esm.js?00d1:3276)
    at VueComponent.next (QueryAcademicForm.vue?f0b2:332)
    at click (eval at ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler/index.js?{"id":"data-v-e5b3dc5a","hasScoped":false,"transformToRequire":{"video":["src","poster"],"source":"src","img":"src","image":"xlink:href"},"buble":{"transforms":{}}}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./src/components/QueryAcademicForm.vue (0.3f605440c8faec0820bd.hot-update.js:22), <anonymous>:364:25)
    at invoker (vue.esm.js?efeb:2027)
    at HTMLButtonElement.fn._withTask.fn._withTask (vue.esm.js?efeb:1826)
```

I tried to replicate it [here on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f1uk3r/bnrpdg01/1/), it gives me same error but there is little bit difference in error message

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: [vee-validate] Validating a non-existent field: "result". Use "attach()" first.
    at Re (vee-validate.min.js:1)
    at vn._handleFieldNotFound (vee-validate.min.js:1)
    at vn.validate (vee-validate.min.js:1)
    at ln.validate (vee-validate.min.js:1)
    at a.validateBeforeSubmit ((index):355)
    at click (eval at $a (vue.min.js:6), <anonymous>:2:4043)
    at t (vue.min.js:6)
    at HTMLButtonElement.Ir.t._withTask.i._withTask (vue.min.js:6)
```

One thing to notice that error is not on every instance of `form-input` component rather only on the last step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue appears due to "in-place patch" strategy that *Vue.js* uses. This case is described in the [VeeValidate documentation](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/conditional-and-looping-inputs.html#handling-v-if). Basically, you need to tell *Vue.js* to track all child components separately by setting unique value to the key attribute for each input element:

```
<form-input key="unique"></form-input>
```

Here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xk0hmn76/) example.

Comment: Link died, I think this is the updated link: https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v2/guide/conditional-and-looping-inputs.html#handling-v-if

Answer (score 3):

In my case it did appear because my HTML dynamically renders based on the certain condition and I was using this piece of code `<div v-if="condition"... >` for dynamic rendering. Despite the fact I was using unique key.

To solve the issue, I've changed the `v-if` to [`v-show`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-show) like this `<div v-show="condition"... >` and error's gone.

[Reference](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/issues/1828#issuecomment-503474165)